# A solvable galois group implies radical extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

THEOREM 18.18
Let K be a field of characteristic 0 and let L : K be a finite normal extension with
soluble Galois group G. Then there exists an extension R of L such that R : K is
radical.

I'm studying this proof using the "Galois Theory" by Ian Stewart and I have doubts about some statements.
The proof is done by induction on $n = |G|$. According the text, the result is clear when $n = 1$. Why?
If $n = 1$, then we know that $[L : K] = 1$ and $L = K$. Plus $G = \{id\}$. But what does make the result clear?

Soon after, the text sets a new field $N$ which is the splitting field of the polynomial $t^p - 1$ over $L$ and once $L : K$ is normal, then $L$ is the splitting field of some polynomial $f$ over $K$. So far, its all good. But then, the text states that $N$ is also the splitting field of $(t^p - 1)f$ over $L$.
Why is this last statement true?

I really appreciate all kind of help, because I'm really stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: "But what does make the result clear?" It proves Theorem 18.18 for $[L:K]=1$. Can you say, why? Do you know what "radical" means in the statement to prove?

Comment: Yes, I know the definition of radical extension. I just couldn't understand why the result is so clear for n = 1.

Comment: What is the problem? You need to show: "Then there exists an extension R of L such that R : K is radical." How is your definition of radical extension? For $n=1$ we have $L=K$. What about $R=L$? You should really try to understand this before proceeding with anything more.

Comment: But that's exactly why I'm asking. I'm stuck on the case n = 1 and I need some help. I'm trying to understand this before I go any further. That's why I'm asking. I know what a radical extension means. My problem is in understand this part of the proof!